# Using dplyr to run rma() on multiple subsets

Tags: r, dplyr, metafor

I want to run a subgroup meta-analysis within metafor package. The simplest way to do it is:

```
model.s.1 <- rma(yi=ES, vi=Va, data=dataset, method="DL", subset=S=="S_Level1")
model.s.2 <- rma(yi=ES, vi=Va, data=dataset, method="DL", subset=S=="S_Level2")
...
model.s.n <- rma(yi=ES, vi=Va, data=dataset, method="DL", subset=S=="S_Leveln")
```

However, it's very confusing to do it by hand if a factor for subgroups has multiple levels. I tried to use dplyr to solve this and extract simply coefficients for all subgroups:

```
Dataset %>%
   mutate(S=as.factor(S)) %>%
   group_by(S) %>%
   summarize(Coeff=coef.rma(rma(yi=ES, vi=Va, method="DL", data=.)))
```

But the result looked like this:

```
   S          Coeff
   <fct>       <dbl>
 1 hmdb        0.114
 2 HMDB0000123 0.114
 3 HMDB0000148 0.114
 4 HMDB0000158 0.114
 5 HMDB0000159 0.114
 6 HMDB0000161 0.114
 7 HMDB0000162 0.114
 8 HMDB0000167 0.114
 9 HMDB0000168 0.114
10 HMDB0000172 0.114
# ... with 14 more rows
```

It seems that the rma function omits the group_by and calculates the pooled effect for the whole dataset each time. What might be the cause? Are there any alternatives for such approach?

Comment: Now how can we plot the results with forest function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do a `group_split` and then loop through the `list` elements with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
Dataset %>%
   group_split(S= factor(S)) %>%
   map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            summarise(S = first(S), Coeff=coef.rma(rma(yi=ES, 
                          vi=Va, method="DL", data=.))))
```

Comment: Now how can we plot the results with forest function?

Comment: @MahdiHadi If you create a data frame with estimates and their standard errors or variances, then you can create a summary forest plot using forest function by specifying its data source instead of using rma object.

Comment: Dear @akrun I have one more question on this piece of code:
library(tidyverse)
Dataset %>%
   group_split(S= factor(S)) %>%
   map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            summarise(S = first(S), Coeff=coef.rma(rma(yi=ES, 
                          vi=Va, method="DL", data=.))))

Comment: @JakubMorze yes, please do ask the question

Comment: @JakubMorze Dear Jakub, I didn't get your questio

Comment: Dear @Akrun I posted the question below as an answer - it was easier to paste the code. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Dear @akrun I have one more question on a similar piece of code (previous one was in wrong window, sorry for that)
Let's assume that for every subset of studies I'd like to add a fixed-effect meta-regression with a binary factor (0/1) - we call it F.

```
library(tidyverse)
Dataset %>%
   group_split(S=factor(S)) %>%
   map.dfr(~ .x %>%
        summarise(S=first(S), Coeff=coef.rma(rma(yi=ES,vi=Va, mods=~F, method="DL", 
        data=.))))
```

If a certain subset from S has only zero's or one's, it will give an error message from rma function. How can I then add a formula to drop such cases from list and repalce them with "NA"?

Thank you,
Jakub

Comment: You can either use `if/else` condition i.e. `if(all(.x$columnname == 0| .x$columnname == 1)) NULL else .x %>%
        summarise(S=first(S), Coeff=coef.rma(rma(yi=ES,vi=Va, mods=~F, method="DL", 
        data=.)`

Comment: If You can update your post with an example that shows the issue for `Dataset` with `dput`, I can test it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
library(metafor)
library(tidyverse)
Results <- Org %>%   # Primary analysis - DerSimonian-Laire Estimator
group_split(Metabolite= factor(Metabolite)) %>%
map_dfr(~ .x %>%
        summarise(Metabolite = first(Metabolite),
                  Coeff = ifelse(nlevels(Biospecimen)>1, 
                                 ifelse((rma(yi=Est,sei=SE, method="DL", data=.))$k>=5,
                                        coef.rma(rma(yi=Est,sei=SE, mods=~Biospecimen, method="DL", data=.)),NA),NA)))
```

It worked, but produced warnings from rma function. However results seem to be corrrect. Thanks a lot @akrun